# Can't find OpenSSL headers/libs when installing Ruby1.9 from source

Tags: ruby, linux, openssl, compilation, ruby-1.9

I'm trying to install Ruby 1.9 from source, and I can't seem to get it to figure out where the OpenSSL headers and libraries are located. `ruby-1.9.2/ext/openssl/extconf.rb` says it can't find `openssl/ssl.h` -- which I've very definitely installed in `~/.local/include` (the corresponding OpenSSL library is in `~/.local/lib`).

How can I tell Ruby where to look for C libraries and headers when compiling?

**EDIT**: fixed it, `--with-openssl-dir=/home/<user>/.local/` was what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--with-openssl-dir=/home/<user>/.local/` was the missing bit o' magic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `-I` ?

Comment: `-I` tells ruby where to look for ruby libraries. I need to pass `-I` through to gcc somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Export CFLAGS with `-I`:

```
export CFLAGS="-I~/.local/include"
```

I'm not sure if ~ expansion will be done. If not, try using absolute paths:

```
export CFLAGS="-I/home/user/.local/include"
```

Comment: No luck. I've tried that already (also setting CPATH and C_INCLUDE_PATH). Thanks, though.